# Problem in understanding an exercise in ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a problem which states that

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $M$ a maximal ideal of $R$. Let $R_M$ be the ring of quotients of $R$ with respect to the multiplicative set $R-M=  \{s\in R| s\notin M\}$. Show the following:

a) $M_M=\{\dfrac{a}{s}| a\in M, s\notin M\}$ is a unique maximal ideal of $R_M$.

b) The fields $R/M$ and $R_M/M_M$ are isomorphic.

Can someone explain to me what is the meaning of "$R_M$ be the ring of quotients of $R$ with respect to the multiplicative set $R-M=\{s\in R| s\notin M\}$"? What does it look like? Thanks!

Comment: This is the exact analogue of the construction of the field of quotients from an integral domain, as in constructing $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Randall What does it look like?

Comment: See this [wikipedia article on localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)).

Comment: What does the words "with respect to" mean?

Comment: In the terminology and notation of the wikipedia article I cited, "ring of quotients of $R$ with respect to $R - M$" means the localization of $R$ by the multiplicatively closed set $(R - M)$ and is written $(R - M)^{-1} R$. (Others, including me, would say "at" rather than "by".)

Comment: Read the wiki article with $S= R-M$.

Comment: @Harry Did you learn about localizations in general, with respect to a multiplicative set? If not, then I'm not sure why did you even get this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

An example may make this easier to understand.  Let $r= \Bbb Z$ and let $M = (2)$.  Then $R_M$ is the ring of all rational numbers with odd denominators (when reduced to lowest terms), and $M_M$ is the ideal of all fractions with even numerators and odd denominators.  You should satisfy yourself that $R_M$ is in fact a ring.

More generally, if $M=(p)$ for $p$ prime, then $R_M$ is the ring of all fractions with denominators relatively prime to $p$ and $M_M$ is the ideal of all fractions with numerators divisible by $p$ and denominators relatively prime to $p$.

This concept generalizes beyond $R= \Bbb Z$.  The concept is that any "fraction" (in a general ring) can be thought of as an equivalence class of ordered pairs $(a, b)$ (requiring that $b \neq 0$) where $(a, b) \sim (c, d) \iff ad=bc.$